# how to create a custom cell renderer for a tile list in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-v3-components

I need to implement a custom `cell renderer` in a project of mine, I have done some search on google but couldn't find what I need.

I need each `cell` in the `tile list` to display 2 icons with couple of `labels`. I need a good example to start it.

If possible I need a way to design the template as a `MovieClip` and pass it to the tilelist for rendering the cells.

Answer (score 0):

To build a custom cell renderer you need extend a class of choice from the available [listClasses](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/listClasses/package-detail.html). [ImageCell](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/listClasses/ImageCell.html) looks like a good start for your project.

You would:

1. Extend the list class
2. add your own bits in(labels/TextField, etc.)
3. override protected functions to adjust the new Cell to your needs (an example is the drawLayout method where you would need to position your items neatly).

Here's a very basic example:

```
package
{
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer;
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ImageCell;
    import fl.controls.TileList;
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import fl.managers.StyleManager;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.containers.UILoader;

    public class CustomImageCell extends ImageCell implements ICellRenderer
    {  

        public function CustomImageCell() 
        {
            super();

            //do other stuff here

            loader.scaleContent = false;
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleErrorEvent, false, 0, true);

            useHandCursor = true;
        }

        override protected function drawLayout():void
        {
            var imagePadding:Number = getStyleValue("imagePadding") as Number;
            loader.move(11, 5);

            var w:Number = width-(imagePadding*2);
            var h:Number = height-imagePadding*2;
            if (loader.width != w && loader.height != h)
            {
                loader.setSize(w,h);
            }
            loader.drawNow(); // Force validation!

        }
        override protected function handleErrorEvent(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace('ioError: ' + event);
            //dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

A pretty good example for what you need is on this [post](http://www.darklump.co.uk/blog/?p=3).
The custom cell provided there:

1. Supports a custom background( by setting the cell skin )
2. Uses a label TextField.

HTH

Answer (score -2):

create a file called MyRenderer.mxml,paste this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Box xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Image id="img" width="123" height="123" />
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
override public function set data (value:Object):void {
    super.data = value;
    // mess with img here
}
]]></mx:Script>
</mx:Box>
```

in tile list, write this:

```
<mx:TileList itemRenderer="MyRenderer" ... />
```

Comment: Read the question carefully.He is saying for Flash and you are giving .mxml solution, which in itself is incomplete answer.