# Flash Tile List with Drag and Drop Functionality

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4, flash-cs5, tilelist

I can easily done the drag and drop functionality in FLEX using DragManager class but enable to do same in Flash CS-5. I also want to show the preloader with each tile of tileList before image appear in tileList.Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check [this one](http://code.google.com/p/as3-drag-and-drop-tilelist/) out on google code, it's extending the TileList from the Flash UI components.

Regarding a preloader, the TileList should already use an [ImageCell](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/listClasses/ImageCell.html) which contains an [UILoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/containers/UILoader.html) (so you can access bytesLoaded/bytesTotal) and it also inherits from the [LabelButton](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/LabelButton.html#propertySummary) UIComponent (so you have a label propert/textField available). It's up to you how you implement the preloader (either following how the label text is changed by the component to use that to display a percentage(%) based text while the tile is loading or using a custom preloader clip).

You might find these older answers helpful:

- [How to handle Unhandled #2044 errors from Flash tilelist when changing dataprovider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214414/how-to-handle-unhandled-2044-errors-from-flash-tilelist-when-changing-dataprovi/3216348#3216348) (to be on the safe side)
- [how to create a custom cell renderer for a tile list in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127329/how-to-create-a-custom-cell-renderer-for-a-tile-list-in-flash) - especially this post and the [imageCaching post linked](http://www.darklump.co.uk/blog/?p=3) in it.

Comment: thanks for this it is very helpful for drag and drop functionality.please give me the idea about preloader in each tile of tilelist before image appears in tile of tilelist.