# load bitmapData into TileList AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, load, bitmapdata, tilelist

say I have a bitmap on my stage, and I want to load this bitmap into TileList component.  But TileList's dataProvider requests URL links to be passed as a parameter but not bitmapData. How would I do that?

NOTE: I'm loading the bitmapdata from Sqlite database, in which it's stored as byteArray. Oh and I'm using AIR.

Comment: There are two `TileList` components from Adobe. One for Flex and one for Flash CS5 (or whatever). Which one are you using?

Comment: the one for Flash, fl.controls.TileList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a DisplayObject as the source parameter of a TileList item's.
If you have a BitmapData quickest option would be to pass a Bitmap object containing that bitmapData:

```
for(var i:int = 0 ; i < 10; i++) t.addItem({label:'item '+(i+1),source:new Bitmap(new YourBitapData())});
```

If you want to do the custom cell renderer route, you can do also do that.
The main problem is the UIComponent's getDisplayObjectInstance() method doesn't cater for BitmapData. I imagine you could subclass ImageCell and make the changes needed:

- either by overriding getDisplayObjectInstance() and checking doing something like: `if(getQualifiedSuperclassName(classDef) == "flash.display::BitmapData") return new Bitmap(new classDef);`
- either by simple adding a Bitmap object based on the source

The simpler, the better though, so I'd recommend trying my 1st suggestion.

Comment: THANK You so much for this! I though the 'source' parameter could only take URLs. One more question though, how would I retrieve the bitmapData later from the TileList?

Comment: The item's source property retrieves the Bitmap object again so you can get to the bitmapData property: `tileList.getItemAt(0).source.bitmapData`.  A bit off topic: Not sure if it helps, but something to be aware of: [caching](http://www.darklump.co.uk/blog/?p=3)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the fl.controls.TileList, but it seems to use a similar strategy that Flex components use: item renderers.

In this case, the documentation for fl.controls.TileList says:

> The default cell renderer for this component is the ImageCell class.
>   An ImageCell cell renderer displays a thumbnail image and a
>   single-line label. To render a list-based cell in a TileList
>   component, use the CellRenderer class.

In your case, what you want is to specify a class that will just take a `BitMapData` from the dataProvider and use that to display the image.

To use a different class for the renderer, use the `TileList`'s [cellRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TileList.html#style:cellRenderer) style.

I haven't created a custom cell renderer for the Flash TileList, but here's some links that may help get you started:

- [how to create a custom cell renderer for a tile list in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127329/how-to-create-a-custom-cell-renderer-for-a-tile-list-in-flash)
- [define a custom a cell renderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fd4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fc2)

A basic approach to creating your own custom renderer would be something like this:

**1. Create a new class that extends CellRenderer:**

```
public class CustomRenderer extends CellRenderer
{
    public function CustomRenderer()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

**2. Override the setter method for the `data` property of the `CellRenderer` class:**

The `TileList` component will create a renderer for each element in the `dataProvider`. It then calls this setter method on each renderer to pass in the data for that element. In this setter, you can get the `BitMapData` and use that to renderer the image. Below is some untested code, there's probably a nicer way to do this (we have nice shortcuts for this type of stuff in Flex)

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    if (value != null && value.hasOwnProperty("propertyNameThatContainsBitMapData"))
    {
        var bmData:BitMapData = value["propertyNameThatContainsBitMapData"] as BitMapData;
        if (bmData)
        {
            var g:Graphics = this.graphics;
            g.beginBitMapFill(bmData);
            g.drawRect(0,0,100,100); // use whatever dimensions you want
            g.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the links. So as I understand, I have to override the dataProvider's parameters? I'm currently searching for some examples

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include a few more details, sorry I can't help much more than this (I'm more of a Flex or just pure AS3 developer, don't use Flash CS5).

Comment: I like @George Profenza's solution, and suggest you follow that. Seems quite straight forward!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for bothering you this much.

Comment: We wouldn't do this if we didn't get something out of it too :) I think I like StackOverflow so much because of what I learn from other people's questions and answers!